# Navigator.pop from a FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, state, navigator

I have a first screen which ask the user to enter to input, then when the users clicks on a button, the app goes on a second screen which uses a FutureBuilder to call an API.

If the API returns an error, I would like to go back to the previous screen with Navigator.pop. When I try to do that in the builder of the FutureBuilder, I get an error because I modify the tree while I am building it...

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. This Overlay
>   widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is
>   already in the process of building widgets

What is the proper way to go to the previous screen if an error occur?

```
class Stackoverflow extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Flight>(
            future: fetchData(context),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ScreenBody(snapshot.data);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                Navigator.pop(context, "an error");
              }
              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PS: I tried to use addPostFrameCallback and use the Navigator.pop inside, but for some unknown reason, it is called multiple times

Comment: Please kindly share us your code 

Comment: post the error as well.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Can you confirm it crashed on this line? `Navigator.pop(context, "an error");`

Comment: Yes. I confirm that it crashed on this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer to convert class into `StateFullWidget` and get rid of `FutureBuilder`

```
class Stackoverflow extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _StackoverflowState createState() => _StackoverflowState();
}

class _StackoverflowState extends State<Stackoverflow> {
  Flight flight;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        flight = data;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      Navigator.pop(context, "an error");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: flight != null ? ScreenBody(flight) : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and of cause pass `context` somewhere outside class is not good approach

Answer (score 8):

You can not directly navigate when build method is running, so it better to show some error screen and give use chance to go back to last screen.

However if you want to do so then you can use following statement to do so.

```
Future.microtask(() => Navigator.pop(context));
```

Comment: It seems to work but it is called multiple times so it pops at least two times...

Comment: What do you mean by it call multiple times and what actually happening?

Comment: The screen turns black. When I check with the debugger, the Future.microtask is called two times, so Navigator.pop is also called two times. I don't know why, but that's what happens. However, it does not seem unbelievable for the build function to be called multiple times.

Comment: How do you learn these things? "Cannot directly navigate when build method is running"? I had no idea, and it doesn't seem there is a good reason.

Comment: when screen is building you can not navigate or call setState, so you have to do this way or you can wait for microsecond using future and then do navigation.